# Count the final character of the string - Doesn't read the final character

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while(i <= len(word_noSpaces)- 1):

    count = 1

    while word_noSpaces[i] == word_noSpaces[i+1]: 

        i = i + 1
        count +=1
        if  i + 1 == len(word_noSpaces):
            break
    print(str(word_noSpaces[i]) + " " + str(count), end = "\n")
    i+=1
print()
```

Comment: very weird code, a word of advice, if you want other developers to take you seriously start counting at 0. Also, always try to write same things in the same way (not e.g. once `i = i + 1` and in the next line use `+=1`)

Comment: When I run this code (after putting values for `i` and `word_noSpaces`), I get an `IndexError` exception.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You mean input - string, output - the last consecutive (at least 2) repetition of the same character, along with the count of how many times that character was repeated.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I am trying to find the repetition of the same character, but my code doesn't look at the last character of the string neither prints the last character

Comment: @JohnGordon simply remove the = in the first while loop

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```py
import re

word_noSpaces="xyzccfjjkkkvbmbdfj"

for el in re.finditer(r"(.)\1+", word_noSpaces):
    el=el[0]
    print(el)
    print(len(el))
```

It will print all the repeated characters, along with their length.

Some more info about `re` package:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html